# Separate duplicated code in another function (code optimisation)

Tags: php

I have this function which is calculating product tax rates and it has to take in consideration different taxation rules... The problem is that this code is working but now i wan't to make code optimisation since one part is repeating. If you check closely you will see that `foreach ($taxationRules as $taxRule) {` is repeated twice, but it has to apply different rule (add or remove taxation rates)

Can you guys please help me out how to properly separate duplicated code if its possible..

One more thing is important here!! All taxation rules must first add taxes and then (in another foreach) remove taxes since there are no taxation rule priorities. That's why i have duplicated the code and not just include `$taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate']` in first foreach

```
private static function getProductTaxRatesByTaxationRules($cartItem) {
    $shippingAddressData = self::$cart['ShippingAddress']['UserAddress'];
    $taxationRules = self::$cart['TaxationRules'];
    $currentUser = LoggedInUser::get();

    // Prepare data to compare with taxation rules
    $regularUser = false;
    if (!$currentUser['is_company']) {
        $regularUser = true;
    }
    $compareData = [
        'regular_user' => $regularUser,
        'company' => $currentUser['is_company'],
        'product_id' => $cartItem['product_id'],
        'subtype_id' => $cartItem['productIndex']['subtype_id'],
        'country_id' => $shippingAddressData['country_id'],
        'country_state_id' => $shippingAddressData['country_state_id']
    ];

    $taxRates = $cartItem['productIndex']['tax_rate'];

    foreach ($taxationRules as $taxRule) {

        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'regular' && !$compareData['regular_user']) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'companies' && !$compareData['company']) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['product_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['subtype_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'])) {
            $found = false;
            foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'] as $countryStates) {
                if (isset($countryStates['country_state_id']) && !is_null($countryStates['country_state_id'])) {
                    if ($countryStates['country_state_id'] == $compareData['country_state_id']) {
                        $found = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($countryStates['country_id'] == $compareData['country_id']) {
                        $found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$found) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        // If any of flags aren't true, then add Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate and
        // check if there are enabled tax rates that needs to be added
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate'])) {
            foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate'] as $includeTax) {
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxRate'] as $taxData) {
                    if ($taxData['id'] == $includeTax) {
                        $taxRates[] = array(
                            'id' => $taxData['id'],
                            'value' => $taxData['taxrate']
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($taxationRules as $taxRule) {
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'regular' && !$compareData['regular_user']) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'companies' && !$compareData['company']) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['product_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['subtype_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'])) {
            $found = false;
            foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'] as $countryStates) {
                if (isset($countryStates['country_state_id']) && !is_null($countryStates['country_state_id'])) {
                    if ($countryStates['country_state_id'] == $compareData['country_state_id']) {
                        $found = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($countryStates['country_id'] == $compareData['country_id']) {
                        $found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$found) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        // If any of flags aren't true, then remove Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate
        // Check if there are disabled tax rates that needed to be removed
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate'])) {
            foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate'] as $excludeTaxId) {
                foreach ($taxRates as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value['id'] == $excludeTaxId) {
                        unset($taxRates[$key]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $taxRates;
}
```

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static function getProductTaxRatesByTaxationRules($cartItem) {
        $shippingAddressData = self::$cart['ShippingAddress']['UserAddress'];
        $taxationRules = self::$cart['TaxationRules'];
        $currentUser = LoggedInUser::get();

        // Prepare data to compare with taxation rules
        $regularUser = false;
        if (!$currentUser['is_company']) {
            $regularUser = true;
        }
        $compareData = [
            'regular_user' => $regularUser,
            'company' => $currentUser['is_company'],
            'product_id' => $cartItem['product_id'],
            'subtype_id' => $cartItem['productIndex']['subtype_id'],
            'country_id' => $shippingAddressData['country_id'],
            'country_state_id' => $shippingAddressData['country_state_id']
        ];

        $taxRates = $cartItem['productIndex']['tax_rate'];

        foreach ($taxationRules as $taxRule) {
            $result = validateData($taxRule, $compareData);
            if ($result && !empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'])) {
                $found = false;
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'] as $countryStates) {
                    if (isset($countryStates['country_state_id']) && !is_null($countryStates['country_state_id'])) {
                        if ($countryStates['country_state_id'] == $compareData['country_state_id']) {
                            $found = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($countryStates['country_id'] == $compareData['country_id']) {
                            $found = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!$found) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // If any of flags aren't true, then add Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate and
            // check if there are enabled tax rates that needs to be added
            if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate'])) {
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate'] as $includeTax) {
                    foreach ($taxRule['TaxRate'] as $taxData) {
                        if ($taxData['id'] == $includeTax) {
                            $taxRates[] = array(
                                'id' => $taxData['id'],
                                'value' => $taxData['taxrate']
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($taxationRules as $taxRule) {
            $result = validateData($taxRule, $compareData);
            if ($result && !empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'])) {
                $found = false;
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'] as $countryStates) {
                    if (isset($countryStates['country_state_id']) && !is_null($countryStates['country_state_id'])) {
                        if ($countryStates['country_state_id'] == $compareData['country_state_id']) {
                            $found = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($countryStates['country_id'] == $compareData['country_id']) {
                            $found = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!$found) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // If any of flags aren't true, then remove Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate
            // Check if there are disabled tax rates that needed to be removed
            if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate'])) {
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate'] as $excludeTaxId) {
                    foreach ($taxRates as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['id'] == $excludeTaxId) {
                            unset($taxRates[$key]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $taxRates;
    }

    private function validateData($taxRule, $compareData) {
        $result = false;
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'regular' && !$compareData['regular_user']) {
            $result = true;
        }
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'companies' && !$compareData['company']) {
            $result = true;
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['product_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['subtype_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For little comparison parts like in foreach:

```
foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'] as $taxProductId) {
        if ($compareData['product_id'] == $taxProductId) {
            $found = true;
        }
}
```

You can use `in_array` function, more information can be found at [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: edit the post after this update so that we can further refactor the code

Comment: in_array returns `true` if needle is found, so you don't have to explicitly set  `$found` to `true` and check it, also what if its not found, it will not stop the execution, and if you don't want to stop the execution why add more logic to the code?

Comment: true, code is updated... Do you see any possibility to remove calling almost same code twice in foreach and make it callable only once by separated function?

Comment: also you can break your code in functions where you take the necessary inputs and return the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146248/discussion-between-talib-allauddin-and-valor).

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static function getProductTaxRatesByTaxationRules($cartItem) {
        $shippingAddressData = self::$cart['ShippingAddress']['UserAddress'];
        $taxationRules = self::$cart['TaxationRules'];
        $currentUser = LoggedInUser::get();

        // Prepare data to compare with taxation rules
        $regularUser = false;
        if (!$currentUser['is_company']) {
            $regularUser = true;
        }
        $compareData = [
            'regular_user' => $regularUser,
            'company' => $currentUser['is_company'],
            'product_id' => $cartItem['product_id'],
            'subtype_id' => $cartItem['productIndex']['subtype_id'],
            'country_id' => $shippingAddressData['country_id'],
            'country_state_id' => $shippingAddressData['country_state_id']
        ];

        $taxRates = $cartItem['productIndex']['tax_rate'];

        foreach ($taxationRules as $taxRule) {
            $result = validateData($taxRule, $compareData);

            // If any of flags aren't true, then remove Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate
            // Check if there are disabled tax rates that needed to be removed
            if ($result && !empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate'])) {
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_disabled_tax_rate'] as $excludeTaxId) {
                    foreach ($taxRates as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['id'] == $excludeTaxId) {
                            unset($taxRates[$key]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // If any of flags aren't true, then add Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate and
            // check if there are enabled tax rates that needs to be added
            if ($result && !empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate'])) {
                foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_enabled_tax_rate'] as $includeTax) {
                    foreach ($taxRule['TaxRate'] as $taxData) {
                        if ($taxData['id'] == $includeTax) {
                            $taxRates[] = array(
                                'id' => $taxData['id'],
                                'value' => $taxData['taxrate']
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $taxRates;
    }

    private function validateData($taxRule, $compareData) {
        $result = false;
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'regular' && !$compareData['regular_user']) {
            $result = true;
        }
        if ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['user_type'] == 'companies' && !$compareData['company']) {
            $result = true;
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['product_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product'])) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
            if (!in_array($compareData['subtype_id'], $taxRule['TaxationRule']['Taxation_rule_product_subtype'])) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'])) {
            foreach ($taxRule['TaxationRule']['TaxationRuleCountryState'] as $countryStates) {
                if (isset($countryStates['country_state_id']) && !is_null($countryStates['country_state_id'])) {
                    if ($countryStates['country_state_id'] == $compareData['country_state_id']) {
                        $result = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($countryStates['country_id'] == $compareData['country_id']) {
                        $result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```